# Accessing a form button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to access a form button...as a test. But when I do so like this; I get the error that it doesn't support this property or method? What is the proper way to go about accessing a button like this?

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("FH_btnHideShowCNC")
    MsgBox .Caption
    Exit Sub    
End With
```

Comment: If it's a form control, you can do `With ActiveSheet.Buttons`... but what do you want to do with the button?

Comment: `ActiveSheet` returns an `Object`, so any member call against it is implicitly late-bound, and now you're coding blindfolded without any autocompletion/intellisense. Don't code against `ActiveSheet`, declare a local `Worksheet` variable and work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ActiveSheet` isn't necessarily a `Worksheet`, that property wraps your sheet in an `Object`, and then you basically have to guess what the correct incantations are and cross your fingers that there aren't any typos (`Option Explicit` can't save you from late-bound code).

Restore early binding as soon as possible, don't chain member calls to an `Object` or `Variant`.

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet

With sheet.Shapes("FH_btnHideShowCNC")
    'Shapes.Item(String) returns a Shape object, so we're early-bound now.
    '...
End With
```

Now that the interface of the `With` block variable is known at compile-time, you'll get the list of available members, and the code will blow up at *compile-time* if you try to invoke a member that doesn't exist (like `.Caption`), rather than blow up at *run-time*.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("FH_btnHideShowCNC")
    MsgBox .TextFrame.Characters.Text
    Exit Sub
End With
```

And `MsgBox .Name` will give you the name of the button which is `FH_btnHideShowCNC`